# Sizing image to the div containing text

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a changing some things in a wordpress theme. Right now I am changing the banckground-image from the css to html so the image will not load with the css, but with all the html. Some code will follow to give some insight in where I am working and will be of use to explain more.

```
    <div class="wrapper" style="

                                                        color: #ffffff;
                                border-color: #ffffff;
                                                                                text-align: center;
                                                ">
                                                                <figure>
                                    <div>
                                        <picture>
                                <source media='(min-width: 1025px)' srcset='http://127.0.0.1/April/hayona%20-%20fields/fields%20-%20image_scaling/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/greg-rakozy-129733-unsplash1-e1524054200639-1920x1080.jpg'>
<source media='(min-width: 1025px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi)' srcset='http://127.0.0.1/April/hayona%20-%20fields/fields%20-%20image_scaling/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/greg-rakozy-129733-unsplash1-e1524054200639-1920x1080.jpg'>
<source media='(min-width: 601px)' srcset='http://127.0.0.1/April/hayona%20-%20fields/fields%20-%20image_scaling/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/greg-rakozy-129733-unsplash-e1524054018487.jpg'>
<source media='(min-width: 300px)' srcset='http://127.0.0.1/April/hayona%20-%20fields/fields%20-%20image_scaling/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/greg-rakozy-129733-unsplash-e1524054018487.jpg'>
<source media='(min-width: 601px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi)' srcset='http://127.0.0.1/April/hayona%20-%20fields/fields%20-%20image_scaling/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/greg-rakozy-129733-unsplash-e1524054018487.jpg'>
<source media='(min-width: 300px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi)' srcset='http://127.0.0.1/April/hayona%20-%20fields/fields%20-%20image_scaling/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/greg-rakozy-129733-unsplash-e1524054018487.jpg'>
<img src='http://127.0.0.1/April/hayona%20-%20fields/fields%20-%20image_scaling/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/greg-rakozy-129733-unsplash-e1524054018487.jpg'></picture>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </figure>                                                           <div class="overlay"></div>
                                            <div class="page-hero__content">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="columns">
                                    <div class="column1-1">

                                        <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This code here is just a section that will be used almost everywhere on the site. The problem I am facing is that the height of the image won't adept to the content in the . this is how it looks right now [image: this is how it looks right now.]I hope you can help me out with sizing the image to the height of the text. I will reply as fast as I can to provide information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Height or Width ? From what I saw the height is fine, try adding `max-width:100%;`

Comment: It is about the height of the image. In the original theme the images were css background image and easily resize to the content, but in this case it doesn't size to the content. In just a moment I will show a picture of the original.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HY4WV16

Comment: try `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; object-fit: contain;` on the img

Comment: I have tried this, but without anything changed. So I tried something where the witdh is 100%, the height is a fixed value in px and the object-fit is cover. This worked. The only thing about this is that I don't like using a fixed value for the height

Comment: Why are you using a fixed height ? just use `max-height: 100%;`

Comment: If I apply the max-height: 100%; to the img no changes appear. The image keeps it huge size.

Comment: Can you update you question with a working HTML example , the img doesn't load for me cuz the link is local

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Just back from lunch. Here is the link of the image I send earlier and if correct is public https://imgur.com/a/HY4WV16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself after some time. In the functions.php from my theme I add all sorts of custom image sizes and select the right ones for the right type of column type.

Comment: put your detailed solution inside this answer so it could help others with same problem